# How to get the current offset of Text Span?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a "search in a document" app . I want when I type the word it the custom scroll view automatically scrolls to the searched word.
I split my document to bunch of Text spans. how do I get the offset of only one of them. Is that even possible?

I tried but it doesn't work

```
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<WordViewPage> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  String previewedText;
  ScrollController scrollController;
  List<String> splitted = [''];
  Color customColor = Colors.transparent;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadAsset().then((String loadedString) {
      setState(() {
        previewedText = loadedString;
        splitter();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    List<Widget> he = [wordFile()];
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: searchBar(),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xfffc3b398),
        ),
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          sliver: SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(he),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  Future<String> loadAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test.txt');
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extend your class with Search Delegate in flutter

Detail explanation and code : [SearchDelegate](https://medium.com/flutterpub/implementing-search-in-flutter-17dc5aa72018)

or you can see my code and see the RichText() widget

```
@override
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context){
return new FutureBuilder(
  future: _getUser(query),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text(snapshot.data[index].fName +
                  " " +
                  snapshot.data[index].lName),
               title: RichText(
                 text: TextSpan(
                     text: suggestionList[index].substring(0, query.length),
                     style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
               ),
              onTap: () {

              },
            ),
      );
    }
  },
);
}
```

Comment: I had a look in search delegate , but it doesn't answer my question. I want when the user clicks on the result of the search it goes automatically to the searched part in the article.

Comment: I have edit my answer. if you do not want to perform search delegate then ignore buildResult method and see RichText widget. may it will help you.